How to set AxisValueLabel position and give Chart complete width?
I am trying to create a SwiftUI line chart. By default the y-labels are drawn beside the grid lines. Thus the available space for the chart itself becomes smaller by the label width. To give the chart more space, I would like to move the label below the grid lines.
While this works using AxisValueLabel(anchor: .topLeading), the chart does not occupy the now freed space. Instead the chart keeps the same width as with the labels on the default positions.
How to change this?
var body: some View {
    Chart {
        ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { i in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("X", i+1),
                y: .value("Value", data.values[i])
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
            .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
            .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4))
        }
    }
    .chartYScale(domain: [0, data.maxValue])
    .chartYAxis {
        AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: .automatic(desiredCount: 4)) { value in
            AxisGridLine()
            
            // Default Labels
            // AxisValueLabel()                

            // Hide 0 Label and move others under the line
            if value.index > 0 {
                AxisValueLabel(anchor: .topLeading)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 300)
    .padding()
}



This is controlled by the AxisMarks. Use the .inset preset to not have the axis labels occupy that extra space.
AxisMarks(preset: .inset, position: .leading, values: .automatic(desiredCount: 4)) { ... }

